# How can I access figure handles outside the function that plots the figure?

Tags: matlab, function, figure, handles

I am using a function that plots a number of rectangles and i have stored each rectangle's handle in a matrix. The function returns the handles matrix and I want to use these handles to further change the aspect of a certain rectangle.
Is this possible?

Comment: I think it is. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but but for example only one border is changed to LineStyle '--', not all 4 borders of a rectangle.

Comment: Shows us your code. Obviusly there is no way we can see whats going on. The asnwer of the question you posted is: Yes, its possible, but it seems that your question is way more advanced. show us that!

Comment: Welcome! A minimum example would be nice, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve